# Wait for everything to complete (asyncio)

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm toying around with `asyncio` and I can't achieve what I'm trying to achieve. Here's my code.

```py
import random
import asyncio

async def my_long_operation(s: str):
    print("Starting operation on", s)
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print("End", s)


def random_string(length: int = 10):
    alphabet = \
            [chr(x) for x in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1)]

    result = ""
    for i in range(length):
        result += random.choice(alphabet)
    return result


def get_strings(n = 10):
    for i in range(n):
        s = random_string()
        yield s

async def several(loop):
    tasks =list()
    for s in get_strings():
        task = asyncio.create_task(my_long_operation(s))
        asyncio.ensure_future(task, loop = loop)

    print("OK")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(several(loop))
# loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
```

Now my problem is the following. 
I'd like to run all of my `my_long_operation`s concurrently, waiting for all of them to finish. The thing is that when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<my_long_operation() done, defined at test.py:4> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7f75274f7168>()]>>
```

Which seems to make sense, since my script ended right after starting these operations (without waiting for them to complete).

So we arrive to my actual question: how am I supposed to do this? How can I start these tasks and wait for them to complete before terminating the script, without using `run_forever` (since `run_forever` never exits Python...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ensure_future` is basically the "put it in the event loop and then don't bother me with it" method. What you want instead is to await the completion of all your async functions. For that, use [`asyncio.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) if you're not particularly interested in the results, or [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) if you want the results:

```
tasks = map(my_long_operation, get_strings())
await asyncio.wait(list(tasks), loop=loop)
print('OK')
```

Comment: How do we achieve this from the main coroutine(several() in the above example)